# Can you prevent receiving downvote within 5 minutes of posting?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I just posted on Stack Overflow, but due to a slight mistake the system bugged and removed my HTML code from view. I received 4 downvotes in 2 minutes while I was correcting the slight mistake made due to your editor.

I think that's a problem as users will give downvotes, but not take them back when it was the effect of a mistake in clicking a button and it was a bug in the editor.

After answering, I would ask that you use htmlentities to prevent it from removing html and just replacing it with web safe chars instead of suggested correct from post title.

Another Problem and possible fix
Users Post down votes when they have answered to try and make there answer look the best,( i have had then even when there answer was wrong)

Make it so if your Down Voting an explination has to be given that way the OP or user can correct the question so it does not get more not telling a users like
First User Says some thing,
Second user, It's Bad
First User, Why?
Second User, It just is.

Post in example: 
[can I click one button and use the action of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140851/can-i-click-one-button-and-use-the-action-of-another/6140891#6140891)

Comment: i don't believe you were downvoted for not formatting your code. You are still getting downvotes (4 now) even with the formatting. People don't like your suggestion.

Comment: No you did not read the Question (that would be worthy a DownVote), it was not formatting it was due to me forgetting to format the code i was trying to answer with was not shown (BUG) as formatting should not effect the text output of the content only the style or formatting of it

Comment: On the bright side, you can earn yourself a shiny new badge if you go ahead and remove the answer.

Comment: @Barkermn01, your missing Kate's point.  Even after you fixed it, it has still received down votes.

Comment: no just browser loading it was 4 after i refreshed after updating the content (the problem with AJAX no refresh) i just did not think some one would pick up fault on it how ever i have recived one after the last post, seeking suspicion it was a dig from this site...

Comment: can you remove the answer then please? i cant remove with an answer on it

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46217/delay-in-vote-casting-answer-accepting-and-better-notification-of-edits

Comment: @Barkermn01 and the fact it now has 5 downvotes? Stop blaming the formatting thing. Your answer features only one <button> and other answers are quite different from yours. If you want people to understand why yours is right, edit it and explain.

Comment: @KATE READ it again and go read the Rules on using <input type="submit" i highlight that a button tag is to be used outside of the Form and a <input type="submit" inside the form

Comment: The problem is people are far to pathetic of these services grate idear but dont cope for peoples idiocy,

Like the post @random linked got answer saying it was a good idear and get still ended up on a negative and no explination why maybe it should be mandatory for you to down vote that you give an explination as to why

Comment: Explaining downvotes, like upvotes, is completely optional.

Comment: Apparently FGITW doesn't always work.

Comment: i know i have updated answer as to why i said that @mmyers please explain FGITW?

Comment: Sorry, FGITW = [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Usually we get people complaining that posting a bad answer quickly and then editing it into shape results in a disproportionately high post score.

Comment: Also, please put some more effort into your writing. Your profile says you're from the UK, yet it is often difficult to understand you. That may be one reason why your posts on Stack Overflow get downvoted more than you think they ought to.

Answer (score 9):

If your answer comes out incorrectly after you click "Post Your Answer", whether the problem is due to your own mistake, a bug in your web browser, or a bug in "the system", then you should **immediately click the delete link to the left of your profile picture**.

After you have deleted your post, you can re-edit, preview, save, apply and fix any and all problems that prevented you from seeing exactly what your post would look like to other users.  In fact a deleted answer can be edited and viewed multiple times.  And this can all be done in the privacy of your gray shaded box.

Once you are happy with your answer's formatting, simply vote to undelete.  In this situation the "bad post" will have only been visible to other people for a few seconds.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, a perfect answer to the question in the title, and it proves that the question here is not such an exact duplicate of "Encouraging people to explain down-votes".

Comment: When you say "Vote to Undelete" does that mean that a 10k has to come along and vote to undelete your post as well?

Comment: @TheLQ: No, it becomes undeleted **immediately** if the author of a deleted answer votes to undelete it.  It is the inverse of deleting it in the first place: if you click the "delete" link, a prompt asks if you want to "Vote to delete this answer."  Again, if you are the author, this one "vote" from you is all it takes to delete it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not my fault.

[image: Han solo]

I think this is not a good idea. Some question/answer are really not good and people do not have to be obliged to favourite a question to come back later and downvote.

So I say, do with it. Copy/paste your code. Double check with the preview.

Comment: now i never said it was not my fault, as you say i should have checked i said i made a mistake but then it should have still worked (htmlentities(php))

Comment: Yeah maybe, but I think it won't be a good idea to put a new restriction on vote.

Answer (score 3):

The present voting mechanism is for the greater good.

Bad answers should be immediately identified so that harmful information is not endorsed through silence. Questions are often asked with urgency, the OP might not wait 5 minutes before trying a solution. We need to be able to tell the OP to stay far, far away as soon as possible.

If your misformatted answer gets a couple downvotes, it's only -2 per vote. You can offset 5 of those with a single upvote elsewhere or even a sympathy upvote on your unfortunately formatted answer. The point is that if you have a pattern of providing good answers, you will be rewarded and the occasional -2 that you feel is undeserved will be an inconsequential contributor to your overall reputation on the site.

Comment: Apart from i have a + score globaly but have been prevented from asking questions due to 5 downvoted questions compaird with all the up so your thought does not work when the automated system prevents you from asking a question, so while i was tying to help and get upvotes to counter it a bug triggered by my selft forgetting to format creates more downvotes

Comment: @Barkermn01: You may not want to hear this; it sounds unkind. Regardless: your questions are in general written very poorly. The question block you're experiencing is intended to prevent bad questions from being asked, and in this case, it's functioning as intended. You will achieve better luck on SO, not to say life in general, if you put much more effort into communicating clearly.